# Transmitting odd number of bits serially

Tags: protocols, uart

I'm implementing a LIN protocol on a Linux SBC that transmits over a UART.  I don't have time to develop a complete LIN stack, so I'm just implementing a frame structure for messages as defined by the protocol.  The problem is that the protocol requires a "Break" field which makes the slave devices on the bus listen.  This field consists of zeros for 13 bit-times.  Any ideas how to send zeros 13 bit-times over UART, when serial data transmission requires complete bytes?

Comment: Are the UART pins dedicated to the function? Or can they be configured as GPIO?

Comment: Sending the commands through a serial port on Linux (dev/ttyS*)

Comment: Have you tried [tcsendbreak](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsendbreak)?

Answer (score 0):

Per [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Interconnect_Network):

> LIN (Local Interconnect Network) is a serial network protocol used for
>   communication between components in vehicles. The need for a cheap
>   serial network arose as the technologies and the facilities
>   implemented in the car grew, while the CAN bus was too expensive to
>   implement for every component in the car. European car manufacturers
>   started using different serial communication topologies, which led to
>   compatibility problems.

If you would have paid attention at class you would have known that:

> Data is transferred across the bus in fixed form messages of
>   selectable lengths. **The master task transmits a header that consists
>   of a break signal followed by synchronization and identifier fields.**
>   The slaves respond with a data frame that consists of between 2, 4 and
>   8 data bytes plus 3 bytes of control information.

You should just send an echo of `0x0000` following by CR/LF.

Comment: This will output a 'break' after every byte